# Errors in EAGLE layout

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, layout, error, drc

I am designing a multi-layered layout in EAGLE for the first time. I have already moved all the parts inside the board area. And instead of starting to route I checked for errors. I got some 1500 errors and that is very confusing.

**Should I first start routing everything and then go for checking errors?** 
I clicked the ratsnest button and it is giving the error message as 1 package has invalid polygon. I do not know how to handle that error.

The list of errors I got are 
Clearance
Dimension
Drill size
Overlap
stop mask
Width

So i think that is every possible error. 
P.S. I have not attached the screenshot for the same since it is german version of eagle and all the messages are in german.

Comment: Before routing AND error checking, you need to set your rules. This sets things like the clearance rules and whatnot. The DRC needs these rules in order to tell you if something is wrong. After you set your rules, place your components and run the DRC again, making sure you don't have any component clearance problems (ignore any connection errors at this point). Then route, then run the DRC again.

Comment: To go with DerStrom8, yes, customize your DRC rules first before you do anything else, and make sure those rules are in line with what your PCB manufacturing service can provide. It stinks when you complete a PCB design and then find out your PCB suppliers can't do it. Ask your PCB manufacturer if they have an Eagle dru file you can use - many do and it saves a lot of time.

Comment: Disable tStop/bStop - that should clear a huge amount of errors, as most of stop mask errors is just silk going to where there is no stop mask. Remeber to go through those errors later if you plan to use silk - depending on your fab house you could end up with parts of descriptions missing (the good result) or paint on your pads (the bard one). And some errors need to be approved - you can't do anything about things like LQFP pad spacing, can you?

Answer (score 0):

There are many sources of errors. You should start defining your rules first. The default set of rules are stored in a file called default.dru. [image: default.dru]

This file defines the building of the layers, vias, blind vias, track clearances, track width, track minimums, pads, shapes, masks, thermals, shapes and some other parameters. Every manufacturer have their own capabilities so you must check with them in advance. Many times, the manufacturer web site has all the information you need but, in general, you should check with a representative also. You can create as many DRU files as you may want.

You should also define the net classes in advance. This is done in the schematic.
[image: Net Classes Menu]
This is the net classes’ window
[image: Net Classes Window]

If there is not net classes’ info in your schematic you should enter it in advance or you will have to define track widths in the PCB manually.

In general, it is quite normal that you have many DRC errors in the beginning. Also consider the ERC (Electrical rule check.) You should address all of the errors reported and then run the check again. There is no definite number of times you should check; you should be continually checking (you should really worry about errors when you are about to send files to the manufacturer.)

You may also ignore or approve some of the errors that are reported.